# Android databinding set alignParentTop

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have following layout (only relevant parts left):

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <View android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried setting `layout_alignParentTop` attribute with variable declared in `<data>` block as shown here:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="condition"
        type="Boolean"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout>
    <View android:layout_alignParentTop="@{condition}"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However when trying to compile, android studio says the following:

> Error: Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_alignParentTop' with parameter type java.lang.Boolean.

How can I set `layout_alignParentTop` attribute with databinding variable?

Comment: could it be case sensitive? Have you tried `boolean` with a lowercase B?

Comment: @McAdam331 I have just tried it with `boolean`, still does not work, error is the same

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had to do some digging into this and I found a [recent issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180666) in Google Code.

To quote one of the project members:

> We explicitly did not support data binding for layout properties,
>   though you could technically add them yourself. The problem is that
>   these can be easily abused with people trying to animate them.
>
> To implement these for your application, create a binding adapter:
>
> ```
> @BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
> public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, int width) {
>   LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
>   layoutParams.width = width;
>   view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
> }
> ```

In your case you would just need to adjust it slightly for the `alignParentTop` attribute:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_alignParentTop")
public static void setAlignParentTop(View view, boolean alignParentTop) {
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   if(alignParentTop) {
      layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
   }

   view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

This is untested, but it should be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: I implemented it through `@BindingAdapter` but hoped for more elegant way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Arkadiy glad to help! I'm glad my 500th answer was a good one haha. Sorry that there isn't another way, but at least now you know for sure that there isn't.

Comment: Just a note for future readers: this code as well as any other instances of `@BindingAdapter` can be placed in any class you like (such as a freshly created `BindingAdapters.java`). It will then be recognized during the data binding process and will allow compilation to proceed w/o errors like the one mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_alignParentLeft")
public static void setAlignParentLeft(View view, boolean alignParentLeft) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            view.getLayoutParams()
    );

    if (alignParentLeft) {
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    }

    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

this code is more universal and does not apply wrap_content for each view